# Batch processing folders with `find` and imagemagick's `montage`

Tags: command-line, bash, imagemagick

So I've been working at this for a while and I think I'm ready to give up. I trying to process sub-folders with imagemagick's `montage` to create contact sheets.

This is basically as close as I've gotten:

```
find '/dir-with-spaces/' -type f -regex ".*\.\(JPG\|jpg\|jpeg\|JPEG\)" -print0 | \
     while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line;\
       do \
         montage "$line" "${line}".jpg; \
       done
```

Using this command, Montage processes each picture individually. The behaviour I want is for find to search down the lowest directory for pictures, back up, send that all to `montage` and then continue on the the next folder with the resulting contact sheet named with the entire folder tree.

i.e.:

```
/media/pictures/folder1/folder2/pic1.jpg...pic100.jpg --> media-pictures-folder1-folder2.jpg
```

A few other things I've tried to come up with are:

```
#This just hangs montage forever
find . -name *.jpg -printf '%h\n' | sort -u | xargs -I {} montage {}/*

#I need a "+" here for -execdir, but I don't think I can use it with montage's argument structure.
find . -name *.jpg -execdir montage {} test.jpg \;
```

The directory structure is something like:

```
folder1
  folder1_1
    folder1_2
      folder1_3
        *.jpg
folder2
  folder2_1
    *.jpg
folder3
  folder3_1
    folder3_2
      folder3_4
        folder3_5
          *.jpg
```

Running Ubuntu 14.10

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the directory structure is that you want to run through?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem but without the folders on file name part. Bellow is a script that do what you're asking. Change `base` to your starting folder.
The `montage` use options `-geometry` to set the tile size in px «width»x«height» and `-tile` for number of tiles «columns»x«lines».

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

base="/usr/share/icons/hicolor"
find "$base" -type d | while read fld
do
  [ $fld == $base ] && continue
  echo ">>> $fld"
  aux="${fld//\//_}"
  aux="${aux:1}"
  find "$fld" -type f -maxdepth 1 -iregex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\|gif\|svg\|png\)" > "/tmp/${aux}.txt"

  if [ -s "/tmp/${aux}.txt" ]
  then
    montage "@/tmp/${aux}.txt" -geometry 64x -tile 3x "${aux}.jpg"
  fi
  rm "/tmp/${aux}.txt"
done
```